# C# List help - 'items' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am making a console game in Viusal Studio and made a Shop class and an Item class like so:

Item.cs -

```
public class Item
{
    string name;
    string type;
    string description;

    int damage = 0;

    public Item(string name, string type, string description, int damage)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Damage = damage;
    }

    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public string Type { get => type; set => type = value; }
    public string Description { get => description; set => description = value; }
    public int Damage { get => damage; set => damage = value; }    
}
```

Shop.cs -

```
    public class Shop
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    Item sword = new Item("Sword", "Meele", "Plain old sword", 10);
    public string shopName;
}
```

I made a list of items inside the Shop.cs class. But I can't call the 'items' List inside of the Shop.cs class? Why is that? If I write the name of the list for example items.Add it throws me an error: 'items' does not exist in the current context.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: your code is not complete, you shouldn't have any trouble so far. Please provide the complete code which throws the error.

Comment: Maybe you want to make those fields `public` or `internal` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to execute instructions inside a method in c# thus the first code snippet is not going to run it will throw an error.

```
  public class Shop
  {
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    Item sword = new Item("Sword", "Meele", "Plain old sword", 10);


    //This needs to be in a method or constructor
    items.add(sword);

    public string shopName;
  }
```

You have to do this because "In C#, every executed instruction is performed in the context of a method".

Read more about c# methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Try something like the code snippet below to fix your error.

```
  public class Shop
  {
    public Shop()
    {
      items.Add(sword);
    }

    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    Item sword = new Item("Sword", "Meele", "Plain old sword", 10);
    public string shopName;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped alot! So other words, inside of classes I need to write inside methods or constructors, but inside of program.cs i can write freely?